# php oop how to work with properties and methods form a class

Tags: php, oop

I am new to php oop, I have a some idea re Classes but I still don't get around how to use its properties and methods in a created Object. I need to understand if the code reported below is correct, and if not what I do wrong.

I am assuming that I have a Class that can do anything for me. Let's call it Class myClass {....}

Now I create an object from it and try to work with its methods and properties like this:-

```
$myObject = new myClass;

$myObject->checkSpeedLight(); // method for checking the speed

if($this->lightSpeed > 10000) echo (“slow down!”); // property defined with a value of 10000

if($this->lightSpeed =< 10000) echo (“Speed up!);

$myObject->keepLightingUp();

$myObject->sleep();

echo ("ligth up");
```

It has no sense I know, it is just an example. What I need to understand is if the way is written is correct;  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this` is out of context, it can only be used from within the class definition (inside of internal methods etc).

Outside of the function, we use `$myObject->lightspeed`;

Also, I'm assuming that you are setting the `lightspeed` property with the `checkLightSpeed()` method.

**EDIT!**
Additionally, it's considered good practice to have a **getter and setter** methods. The point is to not access your properties directly, but through an abstraction layer method.

```
class MyClass {
    private $property = "Hello World!";

    public function getProperty() {
        return $this->property;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->getProperty();
```

This way you have more control over what, how and when you view your property (for instance, you can require a database connection in order to view it, or restrict access).

Also note that the property itself is declared **private**, so direct access from outside the class's guts is restricted.

---

For instance, this is my SpeedOfLight class made in PHP:

```
<?php

    /**
     * @class                  SpeedOfLight
     *
     * @property $speedOfLight private
     *
     */
    class SpeedOfLight {

        private $speedOfLight;

        public function checkSpeedOfLight() {
            $this->speedOfLight = 300000000;
        }

        public function getSpeedOfLight() {
            return $this->speedOfLight;
        }

    }

    #Begin testing!
    $obj = new SpeedOfLight();
    $obj->checkSpeedOfLight();

    if ($obj->getSpeedOfLight() <= 100000000) {
        echo "Speed up!";
    }
    elseif ($obj->getSpeedOfLight() >= 350000000) {
        echo "Slow down!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Just right!";
    }
```

(I didn't know what `keepLightSpeed()` or `sleep()` were so I omitted them, but this is the key part).

---

Other than that, you're good.

Comment: I would like to add that it would get better to add getset functions. This enables one to protect the value and ensure that it is just read only, read//write only or even just write only(!?).

Comment: Hi Ed, thank you for the add. Could you please be more specific? How and where would I add get and set functions?

Comment: Well, the point is to not access the variable directly. I'll update my answer to explain.

Comment: I understand your point. Being Private it cannot be changed. So if I do the way you say I should call $obj->getcheckspeedofLight() before $obj->checkspeedofLight()?

Comment: ..Or it is enough to use get?

Comment: No, `$obj->checkSpeedOfLight()` should set the variable, where `$obj->getSpeedOfLight()` should retrieve and return its value.

Comment: checkspeedoflight sets the variable in the myClass. If I set a variable as Private isn't it enough? So I can use Obj->checkspeedofLight() method to call its value?

Comment: Thank you I got it now. Appreciated.